# Select 1 record in a query with overlapping start and stop times

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to write an access query so that if you have 2 records with an over lapping start time and end time the query only uses the record with the longest duration? For example if I have the data below I would need essentially only 1 am record and 1 pm record for each day.

Example:

```
Vehicle 
Number  Day of Month    Weekday Pre Midnight Hours  Login Date/Time
138         26          Monday        10.98       10/26/2015 5:48:33 AM
138         27          Tuesday       12.30       10/27/2015 5:54:51 AM
138         27          Tuesday       12.28       10/27/2015 5:55:32 AM
138         28          Wednesday     10.47       10/28/2015 5:58:31 AM
138         29          Thursday      10.97       10/29/2015 6:00:42 AM
138         30          Friday        11.50       10/30/2015 6:03:33 AM
138         31          Saturday       6.88       10/31/2015 5:51:32 AM
642         26          Monday        12.00       10/26/2015 3:19:56 AM
642         26          Monday        11.97       10/26/2015 3:20:17 AM
642         27          Tuesday       10.27       10/27/2015 3:13:19 AM
642         27          Tuesday       10.25       10/27/2015 3:13:48 AM
642         27          Tuesday        9.20       10/27/2015 2:48:59 PM
642         28          Wednesday      9.93       10/28/2015 3:41:05 AM
642         28          Wednesday      9.93       10/28/2015 3:41:37 AM
642         28          Wednesday      9.12       10/28/2015 2:53:20 PM
642         29          Thursday       9.10       10/29/2015 3:22:24 AM
642         29          Thursday       9.10       10/29/2015 3:22:58 AM
642         29          Thursday       9.02       10/29/2015 2:59:35 PM
642         30          Friday         8.17       10/30/2015 3:05:02 AM
642         30          Friday         6.20       10/30/2015 3:20:53 PM
```

Here is the query I used to generate that result set

```
SELECT [Actual Times].[Vehicle Number], 
Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]) AS [Day of Month], 
Format([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],"dddd") AS Weekday,
Sum(IIf(Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time])=Day([Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),DateDiff("n",[Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],[Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),IIf(Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time])<>Day([Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),(DateDiff("n",[Login Date/Time],DateValue([Logout Date/Time])))))/60) AS [Pre Midnight Hours], 
[Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]
FROM [Actual Times]
WHERE ((([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]) AND (([Actual Times].Distance)>"0.0"))
GROUP BY [Actual Times].[Vehicle Number], Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]), Format([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],"dddd"), [Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]
HAVING ((([Actual Times].[Vehicle Number]) Like '642' Or ([Actual Times].[Vehicle Number]) Like '138'));
```

Updated coding after responses:

```
SELECT Max(j.duration) AS TotalTime, j.[Vehicle Number]
FROM (SELECT
  IIF(DATEDIFF("n",at1.[Login Date/Time],at1.[Logout Date/Time]) > DATEDIFF("n",at2.[Login Date/Time],at2.[Logout Date/Time]),DATEDIFF("n",at1.[Login Date/Time],at1.[Logout Date/Time]),DATEDIFF("n",at2.[Login Date/Time],at2.[Logout Date/Time])) As Duration,
  at1.[vehicle Number],
  at1.[Login Date/Time]
 FROM
   [Actual Times] at1
   LEFT JOIN [Actual Times] at2 ON at1.[ID] = at2.[ID] AND at1.[Vehicle Number]=at2.[Vehicle Number]
 WHERE
   ((at1.[Login Date/Time] <> at2.[Login Date/Time] AND at1.[Logout Date/Time] <> at2.[Logout Date/Time])
   AND (at1.[Login Date/Time] BETWEEN at2.[Login Date/Time] AND at2.[Logout Date/Time] OR
    at2.[Login Date/Time] BETWEEN at1.[Login Date/Time] AND at1.[Login Date/Time])
   AND at2.[Login Date/Time] > at1.[Login Date/Time])
   OR at2.[Login Date/Time] IS NULL
 )  AS j
WHERE (((j.[Login Date/Time]) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY j.[Vehicle Number], j.[Login Date/Time];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out I ended up sorting through the id field for the individual records and just checking if the next record has a log in time within 10 minutes. I was able to do this using the DLookUp Function. The only drawback is I need to make sure the data in my table is stored/sorted by vehicle number and login date/time ascending.

```
SELECT [Actual Times].[Vehicle Number], Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]) AS [Day of Month], Format([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],"dddd") AS Weekday, Sum(IIf(Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time])=Day([Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),DateDiff("n",[Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],[Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),IIf(Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time])<>Day([Actual Times].[Logout Date/Time]),(DateDiff("n",[Login Date/Time],DateValue([Logout Date/Time])))))/60) AS [Pre Midnight Hours]
FROM [Actual Times]
WHERE ((([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]) Between [Start Date] And [End Date])) AND (DateDiff("n",[Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],DLookUp("[Login Date/Time]","Actual Times","[ID]=" & [ID]+1))>10)
GROUP BY [Actual Times].[Vehicle Number], Day([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time]), Format([Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],"dddd"), (IIf(DateDiff("n",[Actual Times].[Login Date/Time],DLookUp("[Login Date/Time]","Actual Times","[ID]=" & [ID]+1))<=10,1,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going simplify the text a bit to avoid lots of square brackets, but maybe a query something like this would do it.  Apologies - I generally write complex MS-Access queries as SQL-server pass through, so if I do something Access doesn't like please comment.

```
SELECT
  Max(duration) as duration,
  vehicleNumber
FROM (
 SELECT
  IIF(DATEDIFF("n",a1.loginTime,a1,logoutTime) > DATEDIFF("n",a2.loginTime),DATEDIFF("n",a1.loginTime,a1.logoutTime),DATEDIFF("n",a2.loginTime,a2.logoutTime)) As Duration,
  a1.vehicleNumber
 FROM
   ActualTimes at1
   LEFT JOIN ActualTime at2 ON at1.VehicleNumber = at2.VehicleNumber
 WHERE
--Any better way to check two records the same one, like do they have and ID?
--In pass through SQL, I would put all these as Additional clauses on the ON
--ON part of the JOIN, but I don't think MS ACCESS SQL allows it. This makes
--it more complicated because of the left join, and still therefore including
-- non overlapping vehicle records 
   ((at1.loginTime <> at2.loginTime AND at1.logoutTime <> at2.logoutTime)
   AND (at1.loginTime BETWEEN at2.loginTime AND at2.logoutTime OR
    at2.loginTime BETWEEN at1.loginTime AND at1.logoutTime)
   AND a2.loginTime > a1.loginTime)
   OR a2.loginTime IS NULL
 ) as j
GROUP BY j.VehicleNumber
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I am going to try this shortly however I have a question.   You define ActualTime as at2. What are you referring to as ActualTime? I have a table called ActualTimes but not sure where the ActualTime is coming from.

Comment: There is a unique ID field just called ID that could be used to check the records.

Comment: ActualTime is a typo, it should be ActualTimes.  I am joining the table on itself and then using the two copies to find overlaping records. I needed the ID so that I can leave out the version of at2 that is the same record as the at1 version so that complex comparison of times in the first line of the where clause can just be at1.ID <> at2.id